# Обновление GUI в wxPython через промежутки времени

Tags: python, gui, wxpython

Можно ли сделать периодическое обновление при использовании wxPython?

К примеру как в PyGames установить бесконечный цикл с обновлением экрана с таймаутом.

Answer (score 1):

Для периодических событий можно использовать класс wx.Timer.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду проверять